# MissingPropertyException in groovy enum values iterator

Tags: grails, groovy, enums

Groovy code in the Grails project throws MissingPropertyException during values collection find() iteration. It doesn't happen every time, only sometimes and I didn't find the case during which the MissingPropertyException happens.

**Here is the enum class:**

```
public enum SurveyStateTransitions {
    TRANSITION_ONE(SurveyState.UNDEFINED, [SurveyState.ACQUISITION, SurveyState.PROCESSING] as Set),
    TRANSITION_TWO(SurveyState.ACQUISITION, [SurveyState.PROCESSING, SurveyState.ARCHIVED] as Set),

    private SurveyState current
    private Set<SurveyState> transitions

    SurveyStateTransitions(SurveyState current, Set<SurveyState> transitions) {
        this.current = current
        this.transitions = transitions
    }

    public static Set<SurveyState> getTransitions(SurveyState current) {
        values().find { it.current == current }.transitions
    }
}
```

**And here is the row, where the exception is actually thrown:**

```
values().find { it.current == current }.transitions
```

**The whole stacktrace:**

```
[2015-12-09 11:26:51,762]       ERROR   errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /marpinion_portal/survey/detail/122
No such property: current for class: de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyState. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <mpc:surveyAccess>: Error executing tag <mps:butt
ons>: No such property: current for class: de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyState
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <mpc:surveyAccess>: Error executing tag <mps:buttons>: No such property:
 current for class: de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyState
        at gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp.groovy:248)
        at gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp.run(gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp.groovy:251)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <mps:buttons>: No such property: current for class: de.everywhere.marpin
ion.portal.survey.SurveyState
        at gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp$_run_closure2_closure10.doCall(gsp_marpinion_portal_surveydetail_gsp.groovy:245)
        at de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.CrudTagLib$_closure30.doCall(CrudTagLib.groovy:656)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: current for class: de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyState
        at de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyStateTransitions$_getTransitions_closure1.doCall(SurveyStateTransitions.groovy:33)
        at de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.survey.SurveyStateTransitions.getTransitions(SurveyStateTransitions.groovy:33)
        at de.everywhere.marpinion.portal.SurveyTagLib$_closure8.doCall(SurveyTagLib.groovy:78)
        ... 12 more
[2015-12-09 11:26:53,042]       WARN    resource.ResourceTagLib A request was made to render resources for disposition [body] but there are no resources scheduled for that
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: WHat happens if you add a `getCurrent` method to your enum?

Comment: Is that problem solved?

Comment: It depends, I fixed it by adding `SurveyStateTransitions.values().find { it.current == current }?.transitions ?: [] as Set` instead of old code in `getTransitions(SurveyState current)`. But I still don't understand why the old code did not work.

Comment: I came across a similar issue. I could only fix it by removing the 'private' modifier for the respective fields.